# Lazy load of secondary table relation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, database-design

I have 3 tables Store, StoreAddress and StoreDetails.
For now I have Store as @Entity with two secondary tables (store_address and store_details), and info from those tables are wrapped within Embedded classes
So I have one Entity and two Embedded classes for secondary tables.

The reason I choose this approach is easy update the parent entity with related data within single HTTP PUT request.

Bu the problem, is when I make findAll for Stores, each of secondary tables load too with LEFT OUTER JOIN. 
Is there any way, to make Embeddable objects from secondary tables LAZY loading? I think this is redundant load on DB to perform this JOINS for each findAll request.

Comment: Could you explain what is it about a one-to-one association (as opposed to an embeddable) that makes updating the parent entity so difficult? I have a distinct feeling that what you're asking for here is an X-Y problem

Comment: When I'm updating parent entity, I'm just replace the data from persisted entity with data from request(without touching id). So for each relation, I need this to be performed as well. So not like
persistedEntity.setRelated(request.getRelated()) but implicit with all single getter and setter. I just wanted to avoid that

Comment: You don't need `persistedEntity.setRelated()`. Just use `@OneToOne(cascade = ALL)`.